# How to add a VPN connection in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: vpn, 16.10

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10, and I am not able to add VPN connections from the network menu. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

As you can see the sub menu "Add a VPN connection" is greyed out. This was no problem in Ubuntu 16.04.